# Stereochemistry of 1,4 disubstituted cyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cyclohexane

[image]

How are these cyclohexanes identical?

Answer (score 8):

Take the molecule on the left and ideally flip it by rotating 180 degrees along the vertical axis of the diagram. This inverts the cyclohexane without having to break or modify the molecule in any way

[image]